# What is .second used for?

Tags: c++, vector, set

What does if(s.insert(A[i]).second) mean? s is a set and A is a vector. The code is as such-

```
int main() {
long long p,i,input;
vector<long long> A;
cin>>p;
for(i=0;i<p;i++)
{
        cin>>input;
        A.push_back(input);
}
long long N = A.size();
set<long long> s;
set<long long>::iterator k;
for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    if (s.insert(A[i]).second)
    {
       k = s.find(A[i]);
       k++;
       if (k!=s.end())
          s.erase(k);
    }
}

cout<<s.size();
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with [reading some documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert).

Answer (score 7):

`map<T>::insert` returns a `pair`; you'd know this if you [looked up the documentation for that function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).

The `first` member variable in the pair stores an iterator pointing to the element that was just inserted. The `second` member variable stores `true` if the element was actually inserted (and otherwise `false`).

`.second` accesses the `second` member of that pair.